# C language if else uotput question logic unable to understand

Tags: if-statement

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
        int x = 5;
        if (x < 1);
            printf("Hello");
 
    }
```

how it output hello

i expected error but there was no eroor

Answer (score 0):

Because you have ';' after the "(x<1)"
Remove that semicolon and it will work.